# Regular expressions for specific part of string start with specific character and end with specific one

Tags: sed

I want to use `sed` to remove part of string 
lets say the string in file is

```
myfile -asdfgjhg.mp3
```

I want to move the part which start with `-` end with `.` (but want to keep the dot of course)

I tried this:

```
sed -i 's/[-?3$]/.mp3/g' fo
```

but I got

```
myfile asdfgjhgmp.mp3
```

any clue whats wrong ?

Comment: Not clear what you want to do, and it's not clear how to replicate your results.  `echo "myfile -asdfgjhg.mp3" | sed 's/[-?3$]/.mp3/g'` doesn't duplicate your results.  It results in `myfile .mp3asdfgjhg.mp.mp3` which makes sense given the regex.

Answer (score 1):

This one

```
sed 's/\(-[^.]*\)//'
myfile .mp3
```

Or perhaps this one

```
sed 's/\( -[^.]*\)//'
myfile.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

**sed** approach:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*-[^.]*\././' file
```